# Insert names into table if not already existing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unique

I am trying to build an application that allows users to submit names to be added to a db table (runningList). Before the name is added tho, I would like to check firstname and lastname against another table (controlList). It must exist in (controlList) or reply name not valid. If the name is valid I would like to then check firstname and lastname against (runningList) it make sure it isnt already there. If it isn't there, then insert firstname & lastname. If it is there, reply name already used.

Below is code that worked before I tried to add the test against the controlList,
I somehow broke it altogether while trying to add the extra step.

```
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM runninglist WHERE firstname=\'' .$firstname . '\' AND lastname=\'' . $lastname . '\' LIMIT 1')) == 0)
{
 $sql="INSERT INTO runninglist (firstname, lastname)
 VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')";
}
else
{
echo "This name has been used.";
 }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a "unique" index on (firstname, lastname).

Then, when the insert runs it will fail. Just ignore the error (or take other action)

---

Edit: quote from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html):

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row.

Comment: Since there are firstname and lastname columns, unique is not appropriate as John Smith would mean only one John and one Smith are allowed.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You index on both columns together (why I put in brackets). One index. "Ann Smith" won't match "John Smith" etc.

Comment: When I created the table in phpmyadmin, I selected index for both firstname and lastname, is that the same? Or is this two separate index instances and what I need is a multiple column index?  I tried to link the firstname and lastname in the indexes section in phpmyadmin, but it didnt seem to go very well. Sorry if this is simple, but I am quite new to databases, php, and mysql and the documentation has me confused.

Comment: You need ONE index instance, with two fields in that one index. John's answer below has the syntax if young it by hand, or if in phpMyAdmin just add one index and select the two fields before you same. If you have two indexes, each with one field then you get the problem you described in your first comment (one john, one smith etc)

Comment: OK, thanx, so if I return to phpmyadmin and remove both indexes that I could not combine and then apply code similar to: ALTER TABLE youtableName ADD UNIQUE uniqueName (firstname,lastname), that should solve my problem?

Comment: Or do it all through phpMyAdmin. Yes, remove both indexes. Them add one index and you get the field drop downs - use two of those field drop downs to add two fields to the one index. Make sure it's unique (another drop down to the right, leave index name blank and save.

Comment: I did it with the code, it is now throwing an error for duplicate name. It actually found a few repeats already in the list. Thanx guys. Id like to give checks to both answers, since one provided the answer and one provided the insight.

Comment: Glad it's working. So long as you up vote the answer you didn't tick (to show appreciation). Ticks are nice, feedback that it worked is even nicer. Cheers.

Comment: Well, its not working yet, just one step closer, I may be back with more questions once I hit my next speedbump.

Comment: Im wondering if you guys would be kind enough to review my code. It is working for inserting unique names, blocking and handling dupes. Im ready to try to test against the control. I hope to fix rookie issues before I try.<?php

$sql="INSERT INTO runningNames (firstname, lastname)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection))
  {
  echo "
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<html>
<body>

<h2>That name has been used.</h2>
<a href='http://'>Click To Try Again.</a>

</body>
</html>
";
  }
  else
{
header('Location: index.php');
}

mysql_close($connection)
?>

Comment: It looks like it should work, but ideally you'd feed back the response to the form. There is another forum called "code review"that works killer stack overflow that you could post this too and they can give you more feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to create an index on both columns: `firstname` and `lastname`

```
ALTER TABLE youtableName ADD UNIQUE uniqueName (firstname,lastname)
```

In this way, an error will be generated when you try to insert which name already exist.